# sed replace just some letters regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am practicing my sed and regex and am trying to replace all instance of "cheer" with lalaland in the file below, while excluding things like cheering:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-40:~$ cat test
cheer
cheering
.
word
cheerytree
acheerytree

ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-40:~$ sed -i "s/cheer[^ing]/lalaland/g" test
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-40:~$ cat te
cat: te: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-40:~$ cat test
cheer
cheering
.
word
lalalandtree
alalalandtree
```

I don't understand why the first item, cheer, is left along.

Thanks

Comment: @DopeGhoti: bash doesn't do this kind of expansion within double quotes; try `touch test` and then `echo "tes[^x]"` vs `echo tes[^x]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern `[^ing]` doesn't do what you think it does: it matches one
character, which has to be none of `i`, `n`, or `g`.

If your problem can be rephrased as "replace instances of cheer as a
whole word", then the following may work, using the marker for word
boundaries, `\b`:

```
sed 's/\bcheer\b/lalaland/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[^ing]` means any single character except `i`, `n`, or `g`. Hence `cheer[^ing]` doesn't match in the case of `cheer` alone because there is no additional character to match (or not match).

What you seem to be trying to implement is *negative lookahead* i.e. a zero length assertion that matches `cheer` except where it is followed by the *string* `ing`. That's not straightforward in `sed` but is relatively easy in `perl` using the syntax `(?!ing)` i.e.

```
perl -pe 's/cheer(?!ing)/lalaland/g' test
lalaland
cheering
.
word
lalalandytree
alalalandytree
```

See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)